# Cucumber failing in chrome with "Retry later" message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, tdd, cucumber

I'm trying to run my cucumber tests and they seem to stop randomly. A new page is visited but nothing renders on the page except `Retry later` as in the following screenshot.

[image]

I'm on OS X 10.9.3, Chrome 35.0.1916.114, and running with `bundle exec cucumber`. It's happening in and Firefox also if I change the javascript driver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was not with Chrome, Cucumber, or Capybara. It was with `Rack::Attack`. `127.0.0.1` was whitelisted but according to [this github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/628)

> it wasn't whitelisting ipv6 and transitional loopback ip addresses

To simplify things I just moved Rack Attack to be production only.

## tl;dr

`Rack::Attack` was to blame. Unless you need it in your test environment, just make the gem production only.